# Монтирование samba папки в ubuntu 17.04 через консоль

Tags: linux, консоль, smb

Что я делаю не так?

```
x="123456"
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.174/1C_BASE /mnt/1c cifs auto,username="\\HB-PERCO\1CBASE",password="$x",rw,_netdev 0 0
Password for root@//192.168.1.174/1C_BASE:  *
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: строка из `/etc/fstab` не подойдёт в качестве набора параметров для программы `mount`. синтаксис вызова: `mount опции откуда куда`

Answer (score 1):

У меня в профайле записано так:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.129.146/NetBuff /mnt/ -o username=******,password=****,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866,ro
```

Comment: sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.174/1C_BASE /mnt/1c -o username="HB-PERCO\1CBASE",password=$1,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866,ro
mount error(22): Invalid argument